# Explain how to use memory caches in Python

Tags: python, recursion, memcached, fibonacci

I have the following recursive solution for the nth fibonacci number:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

x=input('which fibonnaci do you want?')
print fib(x)
```

I need to change this, so that it uses a stored memory cache and gets stuff out of that to speed up the process. I really don't know how to do this and google isn't helping.

Comment: it is a task, and the task requires me to do it recursively. can you still tell me how to use memory caches though??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution, but will help you learn how this works.

```
import memcache

def fib(n):
    v = mc.get(str(n))
    if not v is None:
        print "Hit on cache: %s = %s" %(n, v)
        return v

    print "Miss on cache"
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        v = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        mc.set(str(n), v)
        return v

mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
x=input('which fibonnaci do you want?')
print fib(x)
```

If you are on Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install python-memcache to run this code

Answer (score 5):

decorate your function with this:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

one of the examples in the docs is, in fact, fibonacci:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> [fib(n) for n in range(16)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]

>>> fib.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=28, misses=16, maxsize=None, currsize=16)
```

**UPDATE**

This only works in Python3.2+

For a backport, checkout this page: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578078-py26-and-py30-backport-of-python-33s-lru-cache/

Comment: @lru_cache returns as undefined

Comment: it is a python3.2+ feature. based on your print statement i see you are using 2.x... sorry about that.

Comment: Or use a memoize decorator http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/